# Limiting the number of SQL results

Tags: php, jquery

SO basically I have a `load.php` page that receives a position variable and uses it to display 6 results from that position from the table... but I see that there's a mistake somewhere because nothing gets returned.... can you guys please help ?

Here is the code :

```
  <?php 


error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include '../upload/connect.php';

$start = $_POST['start'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id='".$id."' ORDER by id DESC LIMIT ".$start." , 6 ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($display = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    ?>
    <div id="comments">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="../pic/logo.png" width="100px" /></td>
    <td valign="top"><p style="width:700px;font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Postat de <?php echo $display['user']; ?> la <?php echo $display['date']; ?> </p></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="90%" valign="top"><p style="width:700px;font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:white;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $display['comment']; ?></p>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}


?>
```

And jquery:

```
var st = 6;// start position...
    var div_height = $("#mighty_holder").height()/2- 50;
    var doc_scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    function loadthem (k)
    {
        $.post('../core/load.php',{start: k , id: <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>},
                function(result){
                    $("#comment_holder").append(result);
            }); 
    }

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if ($("#mighty_holder").height()/2- 50 < $(document).scrollTop())
        {
            loadthem(st);   
            st = parseInt(st) + 7;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What SQL statement actually gets run?  Did you verify that statement is correct, and run it by hand?

Comment: this one `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id='".$id."' ORDER by id DESC LIMIT ".$start." , 6 ") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: missing closing brace on `while()` loop

Comment: @CioroianuDenis - echo out your query, and run it in the database. Does it work?

Comment: That's not a SQL query.  That's PHP code.

Comment: yes, the query is fine, if I remove the `LIMIT` tag it returns all rows, when I put the `LIMIT` back nothing get returned, I re-edited the post to make the php more clear..

Comment: In your jquery, you're initialising `st` as 6, and that's eventually passed into your query, giving you `LIMIT 6, 6` - maybe you should initialise it to 0 instead?

Comment: @CioroianuDenis If you mean that nothing gets returned to the javascript from the PHP script, I think you should `echo` those things that you want to be returned? Haven't really tried doing it your way but using `echo` always worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code, you initialize `var st = 6` send `6` to `start`. Then in the `scroll` function it is passed as parameter to the `loadthem` function resulting in `6` being send as `start: k` in the AJAX POST request to the PHP page. It recovered as `$start = $_POST['start']` and inserted in the query like `6` resulting in `LIMIT 6, 6`. Which will not return any result from the query.

You probably meant to initialize `st` to `0`.

On a side note: to prevent SQL injections I suggest you to perform an `int` cast on both `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['start']`, assuming they should be both numeric values:

```
$start = (int) $_POST['start'];
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: the thing is on my main page I already echo out 6 records from that table (SQL QUERY), and whenever I scroll near the end of the page I want another 6 results from that page, starting with the position that I last left off that means result 7 + 6 more, that's what I want to accomplish by initializing `st = 6;`

Comment: According to the docs, `LIMIT 6, 6` is the same as `LIMIT 6 OFFSET 6` which will return up to 6 rows, starting at row 6.  So, this should be perfectly valid right?

Comment: yeah, but it won't return anything, I don't understand why... I ran this into phpmyadmin SQL and runs perfectly ... can't understand why it isn't showing anything...

Answer (score 0):

This is your mistake

```
var st = 6;// start position...
```

st should be 0. In your case you have `LIMIT 6, 6`. I am guessing you want `LIMIT 0, 6`

Comment: yeah, but what if I don't want to display the first 6 results ?